# Mac Accessibility show my App name wrong

Tags: macos, accessibility

The App I develop need to access Accessibility on Mac. But when I open it in the Settings, it shows SMJobBlessApp instead of my App name. When I run the command below, it shows my App name in the TCC database not SMJobBlessApp.

sqlite3 /Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.TCC/TCC.db "SELECT * from access"

This only happens on my dev machine. So I wonder if it is to do with something I messed up before or my Mac cached something I don't know? I used that machine to develop a helper tool for the App before. But I can't think of anything that causes this weird problem.

Any idea? If you need more information feel free to ask. Now I have no idea what is relevant.

Thanks,
Jerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue -- I wanted to change the name of my app from lower case to upper, and I wanted to add an application icon.

Like you saw, TCC.db seemed to be reporting the correct change to upper case app name, but the preferences pane itself kept using the original values.

What finally worked for me was:

1. Cleaning out TCC.db using 
   `tccutil reset Accessibility` (see comment in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/710308/remove-applications-from-security-privacy-contacts-list)).
2. Making a more extreme change to the bundle identifier (not just change in case). For example, renaming `com.apple.App` to `com.appleinc.App`

After that, the new name and icon appeared.